# Query on pointer in parse.com Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a Class of **Company** which has **User** pointers. The query I want on **Company** class is like this:

Retrieve **Company** rows where **User** object has a name equal to 'ABC'

So, how should I form this query ?

```
var Company = Parse.Object.extend("Company");
var query = Parse.Query(Company);
query.include("User");

query.equalTo("name")       ????
```

Is it possible to write such a request in a single query ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

You'll need to query for the User first based on the name of "ABC". Then in the success callback of that query, do the query on your Company table using the objectId returned from the User query. Something like this:

```
var userQuery = Parse.Query('_User');
var companyQuery = Parse.Query('Company');

userQuery.equalTo('name', 'ABC');

userQuery.find({
  success: function(user) {
    var userPointer = {
      __type: 'Pointer',
      className: '_User',
      objectId: user.id
    }

    companyQuery.equalTo('user', userPointer);

    companyQuery.find({
      success: function(company) {
        // WHATEVER
      },
      error: function() {
      }
    });
  },
  error: function() {
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.. I asked because I needed to know if this is possible in a single query.. Similar to inner queries in MySql.

Comment: It's very awkward to have to create a pointer element, but that does work. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 12):

You can use an [inner query](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational):

```
var Company = Parse.Object.extend("Company");
var mainQuery = Parse.Query(Company);

var UserObject = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var innerUserQuery = new Parse.Query(UserObject);
innerBankQuery.equalTo("name", "ABC");
mainQuery.matchesQuery("bank", innerBankQuery);

var ansCollection = mainQuery.collection();
    ansCollection.fetch({
        success: function(results) {
         // Do whatever ...
      }
    });
```

Comment: What is `innerBankQuery` in your example?

Answer (score 4):

I should say the query will be...

```
const userQuery = Parse.Query('_User');

userQuery.equalTo('name', 'ABC');

userQuery.find().then((user) => {

    const companyQuery = Parse.Query('Company');

    companyQuery.equalTo('user', {
      __type: 'Pointer',
      className: '_User',
      objectId: user.id
    });

    companyQuery.find().then((company) => {
        console.log(company);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Your Company collection has a field called `User` and User collection has a `name` field, then you can search for Company with user name through
`companyQuery.equalTo("User.name");`

This works in Parse 2.1.0