# Parse: query on included pointer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, parse-platform

I have a "Product" collection that has a pointer reference to a "Category" collection that I include on a product query. How do I query on this category value, without first querying the category itself separately?

```
var productQuery = new Parse.Query("Product");
productQuery.include("category");

if(params.category) {
    productQuery.equalTo("category", params.category);
}

...

productQuery.find({
    success: function(products) {...},
    error: function(err) {...}
});
```

what **do not want**:

```
var productQuery = new Parse.Query("Product");
productQuery.include("category");

if(params.category) {
    var categoryQuery = new Parse.Query("Category");
    categoryQuery.equalTo("name", params.category);
    categoryQuery.first({
        success: function(foundCategory) {
            productQuery.equalTo("category", foundCategory);
        }
    });

    // Yes, I am aware that in this example the product query below would likely be executed before the category query above finishes.
}

...

productQuery.find({
    success: function(products) {...},
    error: function(err) {...}
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923172/query-on-pointer-in-parse-com-objects-in-javascript is pretty related

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the matchesQuery or matchesKeyInQuery methods on a Parse.Query:  http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_matchesQuery

It'll *basically* do what you're doing under the hood except more efficiently and a lot cleaner on the high level code you write.